# Change anchor position based on menu height

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I dynamically adjust `top: -50px;` so that it increases based on whether the menu is open, to avoid hiding the section title when the user navigates to it?

In my example below, I have a fixed top nav bar that allows the user to jump to specific sections on the page. The anchor position has `top: -50px;` to account for the nav bar so it doesn't cover the section heading when the user jumps to it. When the display is small enough, the nav bar hides its items in a menu which expands to a greater height than the nav bar. Clicking a section item in the menu will still jump to the section, but it will also be covering the section title.

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<title>title</title>
<style>
  
  body {margin:0;}


  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    
  }

  .topnav a {
       display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: fixed;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }

  .section {
        position: relative;
    }
 
    .anchor {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        top: -50px;
        left: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
}


</style>

<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

<div class="w3-row-padding" style="max-width: 50em;margin: auto; margin-top: 50px;">
  <hr>
  
  <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
  <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
  <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
  <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
  <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
  <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
  <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
  <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>

    <div class="w3-full section">
      <span id="home" class="anchor"></span>
      <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;"><a href="#home">Home</a></h1>
   
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   
    </div>

    <div class="w3-full section">
      <span id="news" class="anchor"></span>
      <h1><a href="#news">News</a></h1>

   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   
    </div>
 
    <div class="w3-full section">
      <span id="about" class="anchor"></span>
      <h1><a href="#about">About</a></h1>

   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   
    </div>
 
    <div class="w3-full section">
      <span id="contact" class="anchor"></span>
      <h1><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h1>

   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   <p> Here is a paragraph.</p>
   
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what behaviour is desired but you might just add `onClick="myFunction()"` to every element of `#myTopnav` to close it when clicked.

Alternatively you can manipulate the style of elements like this:

```
var nodeList = document.getElementByClassName("anchor");
for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  nodeList[i].style.top = "-150px";
}`
```

This might not work in some browsers!

Or using jQuery:

```
$(".anchor").each(function(i, el) {
  el.style.top = "-150px";
});`
```

Although I would recommend the first solution, as it feels the most elegant - at least as far as my imagination stretches.

Comment: Great idea! I did exactly what you suggested and added `onClick="myFunction()"` to every element. Thank you!